# How to install CURL on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: linux, debian, curl

I just can't get CURL to install on Debian Squeeze... keeps giving me this:

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -MT tftp.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tftp.Tpo -c tftp.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o tftp.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/socks.Tpo .deps/socks.Plo
mv -f .deps/multi.Tpo .deps/multi.Plo
mv -f .deps/tftp.Tpo .deps/tftp.Plo
mv -f .deps/url.Tpo .deps/url.Plo
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/hiphop-deb/curl-7.21.1/lib'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/hiphop-deb/curl-7.21.1/lib'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

Note: I have to build it from source as it is the patched version for use by HipHop-PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained, it has to be from source because it's patched (which is not the cause of the problem.)

Comment: Your snippet doesn't seem to show the exact cause of the error, try posting a bit more and the command you ran.

Comment: The trailing “>/dev/null 2>&1” is probably something to do with the lack of diagnostics!